# How would I make a file only accessible from one link

Tags: php, security, amazon-web-services, moodle

I have an HTML file on my amazon AWS account to which I am linking in the form of an iFrame from within a learning environment known as Moodle. Since these people have paid to access this course material, I've been trying to find out if it would be possible to make this file only accessible from the iFrame in moodle (i.e. someone cant look up the url in the source code and share it with someone not enrolled in the course) I know there must be something in php I could write, but Im fairly new to it. It doesnt have to be 1337 hacker proof, just basically enough security to deter your average computer savvy user. Hoping to get some advice here! Thanks in advance!

Comment: not with 100% reliability. referer checking is about your only practical option, and referers can be trivially forged. If you want content served up only to registered users, then don't put that content in a "public" place.

Comment: if they want to share it they can just send them the file ... don't waste your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are important and should be considered. Here is a way to do what you asked for though.

#### PHP script (content_loader.php)

```
$links = array(
   0 => "http://www.example.com/link1.html",
   1 => "http://www.example.com/link2.html",
   // Add as many links as you want here...
);

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $content = file_get_contents($links[$id]);
   echo $content;
}
```

#### iFrame

```
<iframe src="content_loader.php?id=1"></iframe>
```

Note the format of the url in the iframe. You can specify any id as you wish, and the corresponding URL will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you roggan! That will work nicely for now. Im just having issues with files directly on the moodle server which is why I need to access them from a public aws folder. This only has to deter the novice "hacker" I know public files can always be traced, but I just need to hide it under one level of security for now until I get my other problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the file locally (same server as Moodle install), check to see if a certain SESSION var is set, and display the file:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
   die('not authorized');
}
// else, the file is displayed
?>
```

You can probably even upload the page to Moodle (or print it to PDF and upload), but it's been a while since I've done anything in Moodle.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to prevent is people sharing the *link* to the material. Let's say you can prevent that. What prevents me from subscribing, getting the material and the giving it to my friend on a USB stick?

Hiding the link makes it a little bit more difficult for people to share, but I would say only marginally so.

Solutions that could remedy link sharing require you to have more control over the URLs. Specifically URLs that don't work for everybody, or that only work for a limited amount of time.

Looking at your constraints I would conclude: no, you can't (and it's probably not a big deal).